# Wordpress Redirection

Tags: wordpress

I am making little plugin which just redirect one URL to another. My code is as given below

```
add_action("init","redirect");

function redirect()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^/this_is_url/$','another_url','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

I don't know why this code is not working. Is there anything missing? Thanks.

Comment: I have added this line **register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'redirect');** on the top to run it when plugin launch but redirection not working at all.

Comment: If you want to redirect, why are you using `add_rewrite_rule`? Why not `wp_redirect($url)`?

Answer (score 0):

As Nicholas as mentioned I would either use

```
wp_redirect( home_url() );
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

or

```
header("Location: url.com/link/");
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also please note that this is in thought of how you are activating the redirect as well.  Other than just having the init redirect will you be adding a admin_menu item that redirects the user from a settings page to another location?

Please refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin for any Plugin guidelines.